# Citrix Xenapp Outlook 2007 continually prompts for user password. Only affecting single user

Tags: password, outlook, xenapp

I have reset the user's password (not locked out), and verified the problem myself with their password on another machine (via Terminal Services). Native outlook on TS session launches fine, without prompting, though accessing through Citrix Access Gateway published apps page opens the Outlook app, but continually prompts for password, and after several attempts shows the 'do you want to work offline' box.

I have deleted the user profile and associated registry entry on both Xenapp hosts, but still get the same issue.

Outlook 2007 on Windows 2003 R2 XenApp hosts.

I am not a XenApp specialist.

Where should I look to begin to troubleshoot this issue please?

Answer (score 0):

The only company I worked for that used CAG had it initiate a VPN tunnel to the farm in order to access any applications - do you folks use something similar? That may be causing interference with the Outlook -> Exchange connectivity if the tunnel is dropping its communication packets

Do you have other Citrix servers or users to help you isolate the problem? Eg does the problem affect everyone on the same server or does it follow this single user to wherever she logs onto? That should help you narrow down the source of the problem somewhat

If you have the appropriate access and hardware, maybe you can install Outlook locally on their computer  and then use Outlook Anywhere or a VPN connection and see if they still have the same problem. This should help you eliminate the Citrix setup as the issue. If you have use Outlook Anywhere, I've had some success minimizing my own Outlook's password disconnects by adjusting the Exchange Proxy settings between Basic and NTLM auth types

Comment: Hi, nope this is actually part of the internal network, so they are routed direct to the Xenapp servers when accessing it internally I believe. This is just a single user issue and only affects their Outlook over Xenapp as explained above. I have put a workaround in place for the user, so this is no-longer an issue for them. Thanks for your response however. I'll note your advice for future reference.